# WordPress search page shows White Screen of Death

Tags: wordpress

I have created below search page on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/) website. For some reason the search page returns a [blank page](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/?s=z). I have tried editing the code but still I get a blank page.

```
get_header(); ?>

        <section id="primary" class="content-area">
            <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
        </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: In `wp-config.php` file set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` get exact error and update your question.

Comment: Add whatever else is in the header of your template, please. Also, you use quite a lot of tags in places where it might be better to concatenate such lines. It can certainly make life a lot easier concerning debugging not having to encounter things like `<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>`

Comment: Did you check for a syntax issue and turn on wp debugger?